# What are some reasons that the Eclipse console would clear itself in the middle of running a program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making an RPG (text-based) game in Eclipse.

I have tried debugging my code using "System.err.println", however, the console does not show anything, and seems to be in an infinite loop printing new lines ("\n")

This is the loop I have to run my game so far:

```
while(Health > 0) {
    if(!ENEMY) {
    output("\n");
    ERRoutput("CHECK1");
    encounterEnemy(classBase.lvl);
    }
    move();
    if(Health > MAX_HEALTH) {
     Health = MAX_HEALTH;
     output("\n");
     ERRoutput("CHECK2");
    }
    if(!ENEMY && classBase.XP >= classBase.neededXP){ 
        classBase.lvlUp();
        output("\n");
    }
    if(classBase.LVLUP()) {
     output("\n");
     ERRoutput("CHECK3");
     distributePoints();
     if(Strength < 2) Strength = 2;
     }
}
```

This is also the only location that uses "\n" (creates new line)

I expect the output of the code to be:

1. Spawns enemy if enemy is not yet spawned
2. Prompts user to kill enemy until enemy is dead (move method)
3. Check if enough XP (Experience) is earned for level up
4. Restart loop

What actually happens:

1. Spawns enemy
2. Prompts user to kill enemy until enemy is dead (move method)
3. Checks if enough XP (Experience) is earned for level up
4. Spawns enemy
5. Console clears itself and gets stuck in infinite loop

The console shows ***NO*** output at all

For the person who asked where "ENEMY" is assigned:

```
static boolean ENEMY = false;
public static void encounterEnemy(int lvl) {
    eHealth = 20;
    eHealth *= lvl + 1;
    eStamina *= lvl;
    eStamina *= lvl;
    eStrength *= lvl;
    eSpeed *= lvl;
    eSpeed /= 2;
    eDamage = 8;
    eDamage *= lvl;
    if(lvl > 7) {
        eDamage /= 2;
    }

    ENEMY = true;
    output("A LVL" + lvl + " enemy has appeared!");
    showEnemyHealth();
}
```

*It is assigned inside "encounterEnemy"*
(and it is set to false again inside "move()" when the enemy is killed)

The code for leveling up:

```
public static void lvlUp() {
    upgrade = true;
    lvl++;
    Main.output(" _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _");
    Main.output("|               |");
    Main.output("|    LVL UP     |");
    Main.output("|  LEVEL: " + lvl + "     |");
    Main.output("|  HEALTH:+25   |");
    Main.output("|  STAMINA:+15  |");
    Main.output("|  STEALTH:+5   |");
    Main.output("|  STRENGTH:+15 |");
    Main.output("|  SPEED:+2     |");
    Main.output("| _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |");

    Main.Health += 25;
    Main.Stamina += 15;
    Main.Stealth += 5;
    Main.Strength += 15;
    Main.Speed += 2;

    neededXP = 35*lvl;
    XP = 0;
}
```

For the person who asked what the level up method in all caps does:

```
public static boolean LVLUP() {
    if(upgrade) {
        upgrade = false;
        Main.points += 2;
        return true;
    } else {
        upgrade = false;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Last but not least, the move method:

```
static boolean proceed;
static boolean Continue;
public static void move() {
    while(Health > 0 && eHealth > 0 && Health > 0) {
        showStats();
        proceed = true;
        Continue = true;
        output("What do you do?");
        if(classBase.dmg_Spls == true) {
            output("[10] Damage enemy with spell (Damage: " + (7.5*classBase.lvl) + ")");
        }
        if(classBase.heal_Spls == true) {
            output("[2] Heal self with spell (Health Restore: 10 * lvl)");
        }
        output("[33] Attack with class weapon (Damage: " + (Strength/2) + " (Strength / 2))");
        output("[41] Drink Elixer of Death");
        try {
            validMove = false;
            while(!validMove) {
                input(" -> ");
                int move = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                if(move < 0 || move > 4) {
                    proceed = false;
                }
                if(move != 10 && move != 2 && move != 33 && move != 41) {
                    proceed = false;
                }
                if(move == 10 || move == 2 || move == 33 || move == 41) proceed = true;
                if(move == 10 && (classBase.sselcClass == "Mage" || classBase.sselcClass == "Demon")) {
                    Damage = 0;
                    Damage = (15 * classBase.lvl);
                    Damage /= 2;
                    validMove = true;
                } else if(move == 2 && (classBase.sselcClass == "Mage" || classBase.sselcClass == "Priest")) {
                    Damage = 0;
                    Health += (10*classBase.lvl);
                    if(Health > MAX_HEALTH) {
                        Health = MAX_HEALTH;
                    }
                    validMove = true;
                } else if(move == 33) {
                    Damage = Strength / 2;
                    validMove = true;
                } else if(move == 41) {
                    Health = 0;
                    output("You Killed Yourself! (Health: " + Health + " )");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ERRoutput("Please enter a valid numberical value!");
        }
        if(!proceed) {
            Continue = false;
            while(!proceed) {
                output("What do you do? (Select Number)");
                if(classBase.dmg_Spls == true) {
                    output("[10] Damage enemy with spell (Damage: " + (7.5*classBase.lvl) + ")");
                }
                if(classBase.heal_Spls == true) {
                    output("[2] Heal self with spell (Health Restore: 10 * lvl)");
                }
                output("[33] Attack with class weapon (Damage: " + (Strength/2) + " (Strength / 2))");
                output("[41] Drink Elixer of Death");
                try {
                    validMove = false;
                    while(!validMove) {
                        input(" -> ");
                        int move = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                        if(move < 0 || move > 4) {
                            proceed = false;
                        }
                        if(move != 10 && move != 2 && move != 33 && move != 41) {
                            proceed = false;
                        }
                        if(move == 10 || move == 2 || move == 33 || move == 41) proceed = true;
                        if(move == 10 && (classBase.sselcClass == "Mage" || classBase.sselcClass == "Demon")) {
                            Damage = 0;
                            Damage = (15 * classBase.lvl);
                            Damage /= 2;
                            validMove = true;
                        } else if(move == 2 && (classBase.sselcClass == "Mage" || classBase.sselcClass == "Priest")) {
                            Damage = 0;
                            Health += (10 * classBase.lvl);
                            if(Health > MAX_HEALTH) {
                                Health = MAX_HEALTH;
                            }
                        } else if(move == 33) {
                            Damage = Strength / 2;
                        } else if(move == 41) {
                            Health = 0;
                            output("You Killed Yourself! (Health: " + Health + " )");
                            System.exit(-1);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    ERRoutput("Please enter a valid numberical value!");
                }
            }
        }
        eHealth -= Damage;
        showEnemyHealth();
        int allowed;
        int am = 0;
        if(Stealth != 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < Stealth/2; i++) {
                am++;
            }
        } else {
            am = 0;
        }
        allowed = r.nextInt(am);
        if(allowed == 0) {
            if(proceed && eHealth > 0) {
                output("Enemy attacked and dealt " + eDamage + " damage!");
                Health -= eDamage;
                if(Health <= 0) {
                    output("You have died! (Health: " + Health + ")");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            } else if(eHealth <= 0) {
                output("Enemy defeated!");
                classBase.XP += 5;
                ENEMY = false;
            }
        } else {
            output("The enemy missed it's attack!");
        }
    }
    if(Health == 0) {
        output("You have died! (Health: " + Health + ")");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191383/discussion-on-question-by-kutcher-ty-what-are-some-reasons-that-the-eclipse-cons).

Comment: how do I move something to chat ?